# Prevent Password getting exposed (GetNetworkCredential method)

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I am executing my PowerShell scripts in c# through PowerShell runspace. We wrap our credentials in the credential object. However, the password gets exposed when we write the below statement.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$Password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

here $Password will have the password in plain text, which I want to prevent the user from writing any such statements that are targetted at retrieving the password from the credentials object

One such way that I can think of is, that I scan the script text before executing it, and if I find such a statement, I report. Is there a better way of achieving this in **native PowerShell** or any other way?

Comment: Use cmdlets that support the `-Credential` parameter, e.g. [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) `-Credential $Credential ...`, meaning that it is probably more a limitation of the application that you trying to invoke which appearently only accepts plain text passwords.

Comment: User registers his credentials with our web tenant, which we make available to the powershell script in the credentials object so that he can execute his powershell script in the context of that credential. Inside the script, he uses the Commandlets that take the -Credential parameter only. But, if someone hacks the web session, he can modify the script to write $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password and get the password. How do i restrict the script to avoid/remove such statements?

Comment: `$credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password` will only work under the account that registered the password.

Comment: @puneet - why do they need to hack the script to reveal the password when they can just hack the script to *use the credential as is* to do malicious things? Why is one worse/better than the other?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Our PowerShell scripts do execute from the web portal (Asp.NET, c#), and if someone hacks the web session, then he can very well modify the script to include "Password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password" and retrieve the password, because scripts results are flushed to the database, and then available to the user to be viewed later.

Comment: @puneet - but my point was, they don't (necessarily) even need to print the password if they can already get hold of the credential object and *use it directly* to cause damage. It's a very narrow attack model where them getting the password is a concern but them being able to *use* the credentials (without bothering to find out the password) is not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I get your point, but what I have explained here is very limited scope of the scenario. I cannot reveal the whole details of why I need such behavior. I am not worried about the Credentials object, but just the password retrieval part from it. If I just find out the text "GetNetworkCredential()" within the script, and then stop the script execution, would it suffice? Or are there any other ways, I can get the password extracted from the Credentials object? I believe this is only the one.

Comment: Although not a direct answer to your question, another thing you might want to look for if you go the script-parsing method is something like this:

`$Password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Credential.Password))`.

`$Password` will then have the plaintext password.

Comment: @iRon so this means the only way to convert the secure string file back into plain text would be to do so on the same computer and same account that encrypted it in the first place? As in we don't have to worry about people maliciously downloading it and decrypting it?

Comment: @FaceySmile: yes, (till a sertain extend, read the remarks behind the [`SecureString` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring)). This also implies that the script using the `SecureString` won't work under other accounts. *The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication.*

Answer (score 1):

Once `PsCredential` is captured with `Get-Credential` cmdlet:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
```

The `$Credential` variable has two properties:

1. `Username`
2. `Password`

The type of `Password` property is `SecureString`:

```
$Credential.Password.GetType()  --> SecureString
```

so it is encrypted. Now we can use these two cmdlets to transfer/save the password as a normal string without revealing the actual password:

1. `ConvertFrom-SecureString`
2. `ConvertTo-SecureString`

Let's say that we have provided Username as `myuser` and Password as `mypassword` to the prompt after `Get-Credential` popup.

This below will convert the password to encrypted `String` object:

```
$Credential.Password | ConverFrom-SecureString
```

# Output

```
 01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000f9ae07907bbc82458b25fd92b2dae62e0000000002000000000003660000c000000010000000e1d56e48520215b461e09a24c53375660000000004800000a0000000100000008eeb7cf1234bac1806b5b624f4dcef0a18000000c8062d946ab9605dfcaaba9a20d7a7486c54010451c2dd0714000000ce000956b190d080f2c5eae9e159a78916d88e98
```

you can now save this output to a file and read it with `Get-Content` later or save it to a `PowerShell` variable:

```
$EncryptedPassword = $Credential.Password | ConverFrom-SecureString
```

you can convert this normal `String` back to `SecureString` using `ConvertTo-SecureString:

```
$Password = $EncryptedPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

and then construct new `PsCredential` object:

```
$CredentialNew = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential('myuser', $Password)
```

I hope this is what you are after.

Comment: You got me wrong. My question was about how to prevent a user from typing such statements in the script that would attempt at "unsecuring" the password

Comment: I think you got me wrong. The above method does not require anyone to type the password in the script. Above is two separate steps. First you manually get the password encrypted and save it in a file. Then you script reads the encrypted password from the file and decrypts strait to `PsCredential` object. So the script (using second part of the above answer) does not ask anyone to type any password, it just reads the file that make no sense to anyone other than the cmdlet `ConverTo-SecureString`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity: `$credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password` will only work under the account that registered the password.

With regards to the question, you could as well asked:

##### "*How do I prevent users from writing down their passwords?*"

[image]

##### Answer

***don't use passwords*** (aka the `SecureString` class) but ***authenticate*** the user (account) based mechanisms as e.g. [single sign on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).

Quote from [**SecureString shouldn't be used**](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md):

> The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and
> instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or
> Windows authentication.